# Double string output from while loop

Tags: java, string, loops, file-io, java-io

I am trying to make simple one-Class code to copy some definite files (photos) from one folder to another according to a list. The list is kept in separate txt file.

Finally I've got file not found error, so I divided entire code into parts and tested each of them with console output.
And that what I found in scanner while loop:
So the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Sandy2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File f = new File("D:\\\\Javasorter\\List.txt");
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("[?! .,;:\t\r\n\f\'\"]");

        String word, pathbuf1, pathbuf2;

        while (in.hasNext()) {

            word = in.next().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(word);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            pathbuf1 = "\\IMG_" + word + ".CR2";
            pathbuf2 = "\\IMG_" + word + ".CR2";

            System.out.println(pathbuf1);
            System.out.println(pathbuf2);

        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

> 9452
>
> \IMG_9452.CR2
>
> \IMG_9452.CR2
>
> 9475
>
> \IMG_9475.CR2
>
> \IMG_9475.CR2

and so on until list has next, but

Output:

> 9452
>
> \IMG_9452.CR2
>
> \IMG_9452.CR2
>
> \IMG_.CR2
>
> \IMG_.CR2
>
> 9475 \IMG_9475.CR2
>
> \IMG_9475.CR2
>
> \IMG_.CR2
>
> \IMG_.CR2

and so on///
Copying command is added in the same loop in full version program, where "\IMG_9452.CR2" is attached to path srting

So, after the first file copied I got error, because of course there is no "IMG_.CR2" file.

Does anybody know why \IMG_.CR2 doubles in each loop iteration?
Many thanks!

Comment: The delimiter you're using is very weird. Work with something simpler and your life will be easier. That said, your problem is probably that you chose *both* \r and \n as separators. Your file probably contains an image id per line, and lines probably end with \r\n. Because of that, if you have two lines in your file, Scanner will read it as LINE 1 - SEPARATOR - SEPARATOR - LINE 2. You have two separators between each line. That means that between each image id, you have a blank that scanner will read as its next token. You don't want that. Make it so your delimiter is \r\n. Or keep default.

Comment: I would not use a `Scanner` to read lines, I probably would go by a `BufferedReader` constructed with a `FileReader`... (you could also just skip empty words... which can be a good idea anyways if the text file is somehow corrupted {and you explicitly don't want to get errors in that case})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `.useDelimiter("[?! .,;:\t\r\n\f\'\"]")`, because `Scanner` will read spaces between lines as string object, so you have to remove it or change it if you still need to use `Delimiter`.

Also, You can write the file path with forward slashes `/` then it will be more readable and OS independent, and try to use `try-with-resource` to prevent source leak.

Consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("D:/Javasorter/List.txt"))) {
        // in.useDelimiter("[?! .,;:\t\r\n\f\'\"]");

        String word, pathbuf1, pathbuf2;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            word = in.next().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(word);

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            pathbuf1 = "\\IMG_" + word + ".CR2";
            pathbuf2 = "\\IMG_" + word + ".CR2";
            System.out.println(pathbuf1);
            System.out.println(pathbuf2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to use `Delimiter` for some cases, you can use string trim and then check if string is empty, like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("D:/Javasorter/List.txt"))) {
        in.useDelimiter("[?! .,;:\t\r\n\f\'\"]");

        String word, pathbuf1, pathbuf2;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            word = in.next().trim().toLowerCase();
            if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(word);

                Thread.sleep(1000);

                pathbuf1 = "\\IMG_" + word + ".CR2";
                pathbuf2 = "\\IMG_" + word + ".CR2";
                System.out.println(pathbuf1);
                System.out.println(pathbuf2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have not been thinking that the reason are delimiters at all. Now all OK. PS: The idea to use all of that delimiters was to read the list-file in any text format

Answer (score 0):

remove the variable `pathbuf2` completely and you will not have any more of the duplicates

Comment: wont help, the *duplicates* he wants to avoid are the `\IMG_.CR2`  (I think! The question is a bit hard to understand, or easy to misunderstand)